# Is it possible to sort client and server side with @mui/x-data-grid-pro

Tags: sorting, material-ui, server-side, client-side

I have a situation where I want to sort columns server side, or sort client side. That being said, some columns are static and aren't attached to any table columns (e.g. aggregated results), and want to ONLY sort client side for those columns.

Is there a way of handling this, or is it best practice to choose one over the other?